Angular Observable firing twice, first one empty
I have a call in the constructor of a component to select an account (the store.dispatch is in ngOnInit) and it seems to emit two values, one empty, the next successful.  The console.log in the code below will write twice to the console.
Any suggestions?  Thanks.
this.store.select(AccountSelectors.selectAccount).subscribe((account) => {
  this.account = account;
  console.log(this.account);

...

Observables can emit multiple values. If you initialize your state with an empty value, then subscribe to that slice of the state, you will receive the empty value.  If the state is later updated (say after fetching some data), the updated value will be emitted. If you only care about "non-empty values" you should apply a filter, either to your derived observable or your selector.

So you think the state being initialized with empty is the first emission of a value, this the subscription gets an empty value then when the state manager fetches and updates state another value is emitted?

That's typically how it would work.  If the subscription were to happen after the data was updated in the store, then you would only receive one emission.  But if it happens before the data is set, then you'd receive the initial state, then later the desired state.

You could add a
.pipe(filter(account => account != null)) before the
.subscribe(...)

This would filter out any undefined or null values being passed through to the subscription.

That did not work.  Does not seem like the object is 'null' what I see in dev tools is:
{}
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ ()

Trying to understand 'why' more to spot any possible problems in the app.

You could try using filter in a different way (or) you could try with skipWhile
Using filter:
this.store.select(AccountSelectors.selectAccount).pipe(
  filter(account => !!account)
).subscribe((account) => {
  this.account = account;
  console.log(this.account);
});

Using skipWhile:
import { skipWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.store.select(AccountSelectors.selectAccount).pipe(
  skipWhile(account => !account)
).subscribe((account) => {
  this.account = account;
  console.log(this.account);
});

